# Writing iOS Apps development Remotely

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I got a request, where I need to write to code for a Someone. But they want me to write on their machines instead Remotely.

Does any one know any software by which i can access someone else screen remotely?

Yes i can use VNC or Microsoft Remote Desktop but then the Question is then, How will i run that code from Xcode on my end into the Real device for testing.

Comment: stackoverflow is meant for programming questions, not about settings up software. Therefor I think you would have more luck asking this question on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can use SVN, code will be on there server and you can access remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two immediate solutions:

1. you can generate adhoc build and install on any device with the developer approved provisioning profile.
2. generate ipa and install on a JB device.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [Screen Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_Sharing) feature - although this is essentially a nicely integrated VNC client with some smarts.

This kind of working arrangement does not sound like a terribly productive one - many features of XCode rely on quick user interaction - for instance code completion.  On a laggy remote connection these will become highly irritating or entirely unusable.

As you suggest, there is no way to remotely debug on a device. You can however create an [AdHoc build](http://dev.appmobi.com/index.php?q=content/how-make-ios-adhoc-build) which can then be installed on your own device via the web or through iTunes.

The Apple Developer programme puts a few barriers in the way of a contract development relationship - particularly with respect to code-signing - which you'll need to run on a real device as well as app-store submission.   The only two solutions are either a corporate ADC account (you are added as an 'employee' user) or having your own individual account which is used for development.